# How to solve this easy partial integration?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am having a lot of trouble to solve this partial integration equation using the adequate formula.
Could someone show the steps to solve it?

$$-\int_{}^{}{ \sin^2(x) \cos(x)\,dx} $$

Comment: Sorry privetDruzia Actually Here I substitute $\sin x=t$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle I = -\int \sin^2 x\cdot \cos xdx\;,$ Now Using Substution Method

Put $\sin x=t\;,$ Then $\cos xdx = dt$

So Integral Convert into $\displaystyle -\int t^2 dt$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the integrand is of the form $f(x)^2 f'(x)$ and think about the chain rule

Answer (score 1):

**Integration by parts**: 
Let $$I=-\int \sin^2 x\ \cos x\ dx$$

$$=-\int \underbrace{\sin^2x}_{I} \underbrace{\ cos x}_{II}\ dx$$
using integration by parts
$$I=-\sin^2 x\int \cos x\ dx+\int\left( \left(\frac{d}{dx}(\sin^2 x)\right)\int \cos x \ dx\right)\ dx$$
$$I=-\sin^2 x(\sin x)+\int\left( 2\sin x \cos x\right)(\sin  x)\ dx+c$$
$$I=-\sin^3 x+2\int\sin^2 x\cos x\ dx+c$$
$$I=-\sin^3 x-2I+c$$ $$3I=-\sin^3 x+c$$
$$I=\color{red}{-\frac{\sin^3 x}{3}+C}$$

Comment: There is a slight error, antiderivative of $\cos x$ should be $\sin x$, not $-\sin x$.

Comment: @ Ennar : Thanks for observation

Answer (score 0):

**Substitution Method**:

let $\sin x=u\implies \cos x\ dx=du$
$$-\int \sin^2 x\ \cos x\ dx=-\int u^2\ du=-\frac{u^3}{3}+C=-\frac{\sin^3 x}{3}+C$$

Answer (score 0):

By the **substitution method**,

Let $u = \sin{(x)} \implies du = \cos{(x)}dx$.

Thus,
\begin{align}
  -\int{\sin^2{x}\cos{x}\,dx} 
= -\int{u^2\,du} 
= -\frac{1}{3}u^3 + C 
= -\frac{1}{3}\sin^3{x} + C
\end{align}

Good luck!